# Change css style without affecting other elements

Tags: html, css

Now I have `a` element who change color of button to blue... That I want to do I think is very simple but I don´t have enough knowledge of css.

I want to do another class without removing current class, How can I do it?

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/27349/)

Code:

```
<div>
<div class='btn btn-success'>
<a href='javascript:Addlog(" + id + ");' role='button'>
<i class='fa fa-pencil-square-o'></i> Complete</a>
</div></div>
```

CSS:

```
a, .a {
    color: #003F8F;
}

a:hover, a:focus {
    color: #23527c;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

I want to add something like:

```
 a, .a {
        color: white;
    }

    a:hover, a:focus {
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
```

But without removing current css to not affect code that already exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a CSS class then which you can dynamically add or remove from arbitrary elements.

```
.light {
    color: white;
}

a.light:hover, 
a.light:focus {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

JS example, assuming your link has `class="color-change-button"`:

```
document.querySelector('.color-change-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.classList.toggle('light');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/27351/